# Durring the installation of cloudmin I get problem with kvm

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, webmin

How can i fix this? 
Ubuntu 18.04.3 | Webmin 1.940 | Virtualmin 6.08

```
Package kvm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'kvm' has no installation candidate
.. install faile
```

I do according to http://www.webmin.com/cinstall-kvm.html

Yes, I tried `apt-get update`, dont help

Answer (score 0):

The upstream cloudmin install script runs

```
apt-get -y install kvm qemu
```

But the package `kvm` doesn't exist anymore since quite some time (appeared last in precise in 2012).

Replace it with something more appropriate like `qemu-system` or in most cases sufficient just the one with your architecture `qemu-system-x86` and it would pass the issue that you reported.

```
apt-get -y install qemu-system-x86
```

This also might indicated that the *cloudmin* sources might be somewhat outdated, once you fixed this and potentially other issues you could report them an issue to update this.